# Is there a URL that launches the Maps app directly on Android devices, bypassing the "Complete action using" dialog?

Tags: android, html, google-maps

I'm looking for a URL that I can use on my website that will launch the Google Maps app directly on Android devices and bypass the "Complete action using" dialog.

This will work

`geo:0,0?q=empire+state+building`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly.

You are welcome to use a `geo` URL. While [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps) is aimed at Java developers, it shows some example syntax for the URL.

However:

1. Not all Web browsers are guaranteed to understand `geo` URLs, though I would hope that most do (Firefox does, as I just tried it).
2. It may not bring up Google Maps, as not all Android devices have Google Maps. Instead, it may bring up some other map application that shipped with the device or that the user installed.
3. It may still bring up a chooser, if the user has more than one map application installed.

Comment: I think that using a ``geo`` URL will work out great, as I imagine the percentage of Android users in the US with Google Maps installed is extremely high. Do you agree?

Comment: I just tried the URL <a href="geo:0,0?q=my+street+address">test</a> but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
String geoURI = String.format("geo:%f,%f?z=10", mFavPlaceCoords.mLat,mFavPlaceCoords.mLon);
Uri geo = Uri.parse(geoURI);
Intent geoMap = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, geo);
startActivity(geoMap);
```

This does not call the

```
Intent.createChooser()
```